# React Native - inline pressable component with hitSlop inline with text

Tags: react-native, flexbox

A client wants a paragraph of text in a React Native app, where there is inline text that is pressable. The problem is that I can't put *hitSlop* on a *Text* and if I use *TouchableOpacity*, it won't display inline with the text - each is its own block.

Here is what I've tried:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={ styles.text }>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi </Text>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={ () => Alert.alert('howdy') }
          hitSlop={ { top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15, left: 15 } }
        >
          <Text style={ styles.buttonText }>ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={ styles.text }>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  text: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'red',
  }
});
```

There is a snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kevinsmithwebdev/thrilled-cheese).

Is there a way to get some hitSlop on a *Text*? Or is there a way to get a *TouchableOpacity* inline with other text? In either case, the *hitSlop* would need to overlap the inert text that surrounds it.

Any ideas? Thanx.

Addendum: I forgot to mention that on Android, you can't have a *View* (which *TouchableOpacity* inherits) as a child of a *Text*. It works on iOS but not Android, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It is actually possible to put a TouchableWithoutFeedback inside a Text Element on Android. https://snack.expo.io/rJWVzXKbS TouchableOpactiy probably doesn't work because it actually converts into an Animated.View. But even with this, hitSlop doesn't work surrounded by other text elements because I think they capture the touch instead.

Comment: I wasn't able to come up with a good solution. Your solution doesn't crash but also isn't inline.

Comment: well, if you don't care about the `hitSlop` prop anymore you can just use `onPress` directly on a `Text` element. When I view this code in the snack emulator it seems to be inlined, maybe its different in an actual project?

Comment: Yes, my interest was in getting both - inline and hitSlop that extended over non-pressable text. I can get either alone.

Answer (score 3):

Your original solution is very close. The reason it doesn't work is because `flexWrap` keeps entire elements (`View` or `Text`) together rather than wrapping at the nearest word.

You can get around this by splitting your long text string and creating a separate `TouchableOpacity` for each word. That way `flexWrap` will behave like a normal word wrap.

Here's the [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/HJlu_J7ar)

```
const touchableText = 'ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.';
const loremText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.';
const ipsumText = 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <CompoundText text={loremText} />
    <CompoundTextLink text={touchableText} />
    <CompoundText text={ipsumText} />
  </View>
);

const CompoundText = ({text}) => 
  text.split(' ').map(word => <Text>{word} </Text>);

const CompoundTextLink = ({ text }) => 
  text.split(' ').map(word => <TextLink word={word} />);

const TextLink = ({ word }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    hitSlop={{top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10}}
    onPress={() => Alert.alert('howdy')}
    style={styles.zIndex1}
  >
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{word} </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'red',
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this effect the performance?